# Solving quadratic recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I'm seeking a solution (if one is known to exist) to the following recurrence relation:

$x_{t+1}^2 = ax_t+bx_t^2$.

where $a\in(0,1)$, $b\in(0,1)$. I know $x_0\in(1,3)$, but its value varies case-by-case within that range. Ideally the solution would be of the form $x_t = f(x_0,a,b,t)$.

Any help solving this? Is there hope? Thanks in advance!

John

Comment: Are you looking for an explicit expression for the solution, of the form $x_t = f(a,b,x_0,t)$ ?

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what I am looking for...

Comment: I'd say this is quite hopeless.