# A recurrence relation question - transforming

Tags: recurrence-relations

$a_{n+1}+{a_n}^2-2a_n=0$

I guess it is solved by transforming $a_n$ to some form of $b_n$. But I could not see the way. Would you explain the solution in details? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: The change of variable $b_n=a_n-1$ leads to $$b_{n+1}=-b_n^2.$$ Can you check this and complete the proof?

Answer (score -1):

Note that
$$\begin{align}
a_{n+1}+{a_n}^2-2a_n=0 & \iff a_{n+1} = -a_n^2 + 2a_n \\
& \iff a_{n+1}=-(a_n^2-2a_n+1)+1 \\
& \iff a_{n+1}=-(a_n-1)^2+1 \\
\end{align}$$
and a simple heurist reasoning suggests that
$$a_n \approx -( \ldots ((a_0^2)^2)^2 \ldots )^2 = -a_1 ^ {2^n}$$

Now, since solving quadratic recurrence relation [*is quite hopeless*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477094/solving-quadratic-recurrence-relation)  because [*most quadratic maps are not solvable*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticMap.html) (however there are some [tricks](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704350/solve-a-quadratic-map) you can try) the first thing to try is to give some values, and one can see that
$$\begin{cases}
a_1 = 1 \Rightarrow a_n = 1 \qquad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}\\
a_1 = 2 \Rightarrow a_n = 0 \qquad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n \ge 2\\
a_1 = 3 \Rightarrow a_2 = -3, a_3 = -15, a_4 = -255, a_5 = 65535 \ldots
\end{cases}$$
and it's clearly visible a pattern $\ldots$
$$a_{n} = -(a_1 -1)^{2^n}+1$$

Comment: How is this a hint?

Comment: sorry, edited to make clearer